# Class not registered exception: BitmapImage

Tags: xunit, winui-3

When I try to create a `BitmapImage` instance (under WinUI 3) I get an exception that a necessary class is not registered. This is taking place within Visual Studio 2022, within an xUnit based test project.

The line throwing the exception is simply:

```
var retVal = new BitmapImage();
```

Given how simple the line is I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my xUnit project setup. Here it is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
      <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MapLibraryWinApp\MapLibraryWinApp.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here's the project file for the library containing the code I'm trying to test:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
        <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>

        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <RootNamespace>J4JSoftware.MapLibrary</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>J4JSoftware.MapLibraryWinApp</AssemblyName>
        <AssemblyTitle>Map Library (Windows Apps)</AssemblyTitle>
        <Version>0.5.0</Version>
        <Copyright>Copyright © Mark A. Olbert</Copyright>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22000.197" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities" Version="2.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\J4JLogging\J4JLogging\J4JLogging.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\MapLibrary\MapLibrary.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I thought perhaps the test project might need to contain the `<UseWinUI>` tag, but adding it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run an actual packaged WinUI app or [deploy the Windows App SDK runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/deploy-unpackaged-apps?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) along with a non-MSIX-packaged app to be able to use the WinUI types.

I am afraid it's not as simple as simply referencing the WinUI code from a standalone testrunner app.

Please refer to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/winui-desktop-unit-tests?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) blog post for an example of how to set up an actual app that runs the tests. Or avoid creating UI specific stuff in your unit tests.

Comment: Thanx, always good to learn something you're trying is impossible so you stop wasting time attempting it :). Interestingly, there is a feature request on github requesting templates for WinUI/WinApp test projects (they currently exist for UWP but not WinUI/WinApp).